# How to generate .ini file only contain value?

Tags: python, ini, configparser

Could python `configparser`  module generate .ini file as follows:

```
sample               (this entire line written to outfiles)
other comments       (this entire line discarded)

IOFILES                    Keyword, don't edit this line 
tset.txt               Name of input meteorological data file
test                       Prefix for output file 

CONTROL                    Keyword, don't edit this line
1                          (int) Number of header lines in input file
11680                       (int) Number of days of data in input file

PARAMETERS                 Keyword, don't edit this line
500.0                      (double) Base station elevation, meters
50.0                       (double) Base station annual precip isohyet, cm
48.0                       (double) Site latitude, degrees (- for south)

END                        Keyword, don't edit this line
```

All the parameters valuses set flush, and use space to seperate valuse and  parameters illustrators.

I will build many ini files like above used as .exe program parameter setting. Different ini file with different parameters, but could generate through a loop. Are there any other ways to accomplish?

Comment: any reasons to pick this weird format?

Comment: Some .exe programs compiled from C++ need such ini file.